# Importing @angular/core when creating a service only module?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code

### Summary

Attempting to get read of red squiggly line in visual studio code warning that `@angular/core` cannot be resolved.  Thoughts?

### Details

I'm creating a service only module to be published to NPM.  I have `@angular/core` as a peer dependency in `package.json` and I have it installed.  I placed the service in an lib folder and within it I have `import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';`, however Visual Studio Code draws a red squiggly line underneath it and hovering reveals the message `[ts] cannot find the module @angular/core`.

This is what the dependencies in `package.json` look like and they are all installed:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "@angular/core": "*"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.9",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.9",
  "rollup": "^0.57.0",
  "typescript": "^2.7.2",
  "uglify-js": "^3.3.15"
}
```

Also tried adding:

```
"paths": {
  "@angular/core": ["node_modules/@angular/core"],
}
```

To `tsconfig.json` but the red squiggly is still there.

Took a screenshot of the setup so far:

[image]

Comment: add @angular/core to dev dependencies too

Comment: Tried that but VSC still draws the red squigglys

Comment: did u run npm install after adding it to devdependencies? can u provide a plunk? Seems like a directory issue.

Comment: try adding this  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "../dist",} and change your ourDir to '../dist'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`peerDependencies` is meant to be used by the consumer of your package. It indicates that your library needs that package installed, but doesn't make NPM install it. For development, add '@angular\core' also to devDependencies and then run `npm install` again.

Comment: I added it in dev dependencies as well and verified installation (See screenshot of node_modules folder), but the red squigglies are still there.

Comment: I started from scratch and ran `npm i --save-dev @angular/core` first and then tried to import it.  It works, so there must have been something wrong somewhere else.  Thanks!